# VB DataGridView Calculation?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

this is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    Dim newTable As New DataTable

    newTable.Columns.Add("Column1")
    newTable.Columns.Add("Column2")
    newTable.Columns.Add("Column3")

    newTable.Rows.Add("1", "4", "")
    newTable.Rows.Add("10", "2", "")
    newTable.Rows.Add("20", "5", "")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = newTable

    Try
        Dim iCell1 As Integer
        Dim icell2 As Integer
        Dim icellResult As Integer
        iCell1 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        icell2 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        icellResult = iCell1 * icell2
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = icellResult
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the Column3 = column1 * column2. 
In my code above, only on the 1st row correct. I want the column 3 appear value 4, 20, and 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        newTable.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = newTable.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value * newTable.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    Next
```

Comment: At the end of Load sub, in place of DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = icellResult

Answer (score 0):

your code like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    Dim newTable As New DataTable

    newTable.Columns.Add("Column1")
    newTable.Columns.Add("Column2")
    newTable.Columns.Add("Column3")

    newTable.Rows.Add("1", "4", "")
    newTable.Rows.Add("10", "2", "")
    newTable.Rows.Add("20", "5", "")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = newTable

    Try
       For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        newTable.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = newTable.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value * newTable.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        Next 

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for your code`

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueNeeded
    With DataGridView1
        If e.ColumnIndex = 2 And Not (TypeOf (.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value) Is DBNull OrElse _
                                      TypeOf (.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value) Is DBNull) Then
            Dim i, j As Integer

            i = CInt(.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value)
            j = CInt(.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value)
            e.Value = i * j
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```